# groupby and join text column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with this header `text|business_id`

I wanna group all texts related to one business

I used `review_data=review_data.groupby(['business_id'])['text'].apply("".join)`

The `review_data` is like:

```
                                                   text  \
0     mr hoagi institut walk doe seem like throwback...   
1     excel food superb custom servic miss mario mac...   
2     yes place littl date open weekend staff alway ... 

         business_id  
0     5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANhGckJw  
1     5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANhGckJw  
2     5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANhGckJw
```

I get this error: `TypeError: sequence item 131: expected string, float found`

these are the lines 130 to 132:

```
130 use order fair often  past 2 year food get progress wors everi time order  doesnt help owner alway regist rude everi time  final decid im done  dont think feel let inconveni order food restaur  let alon one food isnt even good also insid dirti heck  deliv food bmw cant buy scrub brush  found golden dragon collier squar 100 time better|SQ0j7bgSTazkVQlF5AnqyQ
131 popular denni|wqu7ILomIOPSduRwoWp4AQ
132 want smth quick late night would say denni|wqu7ILomIOPSduRwoWp4AQ
```

Comment: Does `review_data=review_data.groupby(['business_id'])['text'].apply("".join)` work? it looks like you're concatenating the index number

Comment: yes, that's what wanted. but I still get errors while reading some lines: TypeError: sequence item 131: expected string, float found

Comment: That means you have missing data, you'll have to post sample data that reproduces this error and code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need filter [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) data with [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) before `groupby`:

```
print review_data
          text             business_id
0    mr hoagi   5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANhGckJw
1  excel food   5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANhGckJw
2          NaN  5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANhGckJw
3   yes place   5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANhGckJw


review_data = review_data[review_data['text'].notnull()]
print review_data
          text             business_id
0    mr hoagi   5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANhGckJw
1  excel food   5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANhGckJw
3   yes place   5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANhGckJw

review_data=review_data.groupby(['business_id'])['text'].apply("".join)
print review_data
business_id
5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANhGckJw    mr hoagi excel food yes place 
Name: text, dtype: object
```